# Redirect url with Trailing slash in the end of every url

Tags: sitecore-client, links, redirect

I have a requirement where I need to redirect every URL and add trailing / in the end.

Example : [www.site1.com/abc](http://www.site1.com/abc) should redirect to [www.site1.com/abc/](http://www.site1.com/abc/).

Forward slash "/" should be added to every URL. How to handle this in Sitecore?

Comment: If you have CDN that supports redirects like Cloudflare, you can handle this there as well. If you want to handle it in Sitecore, you can make use of several redirect modules present in Sitecore marketplace -https://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#qr=redirect.

Comment: Can't handle at Cloudflare level. Need to Handle at application level. Is there way to handle in SItecore via Some Pipelines. Not using any Modules.

Comment: You can create pipeline after ItemResolver processor and add your logic there.

Comment: That really should not happen in Sitecore. That's purely wasting resources if you need Sitecore handling this. Use IIS Rewrite module as suggested by Guarav in his answer

Comment: You can add a hook at httprequestbegin pipeline to evaluate incoming URL and do the redirects. Only problem is it will intercept each incoming request which is why we should depend on pipelines as last resort only.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding below in `web.config` in the `<rewrite>` section -

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Can't Use IIS redirects. Is there way to handle in Sitecore.

Comment: Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385265/add-a-trailing-slash-at-the-end-of-each-url

Comment: As @marekmusielak mentioned in the comment, this really should not happen in Sitecore. That's purely wasting resources if you need Sitecore handling this. What is the reason for adding in web.config? not